# Processing random matrices

Tags: optimization, performance, beginner, matrix, matlab

I am doing my research about scheduling by using Matlab. I am a new Matlab user and I have a problem with time execution of my following code:

```
clc
clear all
A=8;
B=12;
C=10;
ProcessTime= [ 11 11 11 11 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 ]; %Converting Matrice

RandomMatriceA=zeros(A,B,C);
RandomMatriceB=zeros(A,B,C);
SumRandomMatriceB=zeros(1,A,C);
ConvertMatriceA=zeros(A,B,C);
ProcessRandomMatriceA=zeros(A,B,C);
StartProcess=zeros(A,B,C);
EndProcess=zeros(A,B,C);
StartPost=zeros(A,B,C);

for ii=1:C;    
    for x=1:2:A-1;
        %make first random matrice
        [vals RandomMatriceA(x,:,ii)]=sort(rand(1,B),2); %batasan tidak boleh satu kelompok melakukan lebih dari satu aktivitas dalam satu waktu   
        done=false;
        while ~done,
              %make row of second random matrice
              NewRowRandomMatriceB=randi([0 2],1,B);
              %Make sure sum all element per row in RandomMatriceB <=11
              done=sum(NewRowRandomMatriceB)<12;
        end
        RandomMatriceB(x,:,ii)=NewRowRandomMatriceB;
        %After making RandomMatriceA and RandomMatriceB, then Make New
        %Matrice
        %To know varible of new matrice which is result of combining
        %RandomMatriceA,RandomMatriceB and ProcessTime
        for y=1:B,
            ConvertMatriceA(x,y,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(x,y,ii));%FirstVarible:Consecutive The Number of value in all element of RandomMatriceA
        end
        ProcessRandomMatriceA(x,:,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(x,:,ii))+RandomMatriceB(x,:,ii);
        EndProcess(x,:,ii)=cumsum(ProcessRandomMatriceA(x,:,ii),2);%secondVaribale:to know in which column The Consecutive value RandomMatrice will be end
        StartProcess(x,:,ii)=EndProcess(x,:,ii)-(ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(x,:,ii))-1);%ThirdVariable:to know in which column The Consecutive Value will be start
        for yy=1:B;
            N=RandomMatriceA(x,yy,ii);
            StartPost(x,N,ii)=StartProcess(x,yy,ii);
        end 
    end
    for h=2:2:A;
        doneA=false;
        while ~doneA,
          [vals RandomMatriceA(h,:,ii)]=sort(rand(1,B),2);
          doneB=false;
          while ~doneB,
                 NewRowRandomMatriceB=randi([0 2],1,B);
                 doneB= sum(NewRowRandomMatriceB)<12;
          end
          RandomMatriceB(h,:,ii)=NewRowRandomMatriceB;
          for y=1:B;
              ConvertMatriceA(h,y,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(h,y,ii));
          end
          ProcessRandomMatriceA(h,:,ii)=ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(h,:,ii))+RandomMatriceB(h,:,ii);
          EndProcess(h,:,ii)=cumsum(ProcessRandomMatriceA(h,:,ii),2);%secondVaribale:to know in which column The Consecutive value RandomMatrice will be end
          StartProcess(h,:,ii)=EndProcess(h,:,ii)-(ProcessTime(RandomMatriceA(h,:,ii))-1);%ThirdVariable:to know in which column The Consecutive Value will be start
          for z=1:B;
            N=RandomMatriceA(h,z,ii);
            StartPost(h,N,ii)=StartProcess(h,z,ii);
          end 
           doneA =all(ismember(StartPost(h,1:4,ii),StartPost(h-1,1:4,ii)));
        end
        %arrange value in column 1 until 4 in order that it will have same
        %value
        StartPost(h,1:4,ii)=StartPost(h-1,1:4,ii);
    end   
end
```

After using the profile viewer, I know that my problem is in this following code. This part takes too much execution time.

```
....
end 
           doneA =all(ismember(StartPost(h,1:4,ii),StartPost(h-1,1:4,ii)));
        end
        %arrange value in column 1 until 4 in order that it will have same
        %value
        StartPost(h,1:4,ii)=StartPost(h-1,1:4,ii);
    end
```

How can I improve it and make it run faster?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess given the information:
You are doing some expensive ismember operations. You can try to get rid of them by tracking Done in a different way.

Perhaps you can use a more efficent way to do it in the same location, or perhaps you need to move it inside the loop and do it in a very cheap way there.

Comment: +1 - ismember is one of the slowest things you can do in matlab. ismember inside a loop is a real performance killer. Anyway all this code is not properly vectorized.